# About Neo4j internal data storage

Tags: neo4j, structure, internal

I was looking at the data files storage in Neo4j and I came up with interrogations.

I followed those two articles :
http://digitalstain.blogspot.jp/2010/10/neo4j-internals-file-storage.html
http://digitalstain.blogspot.jp/2011/11/rooting-out-redundancy-new-neo4j.html

I'm working with Neo4j 2.0.0

Here are my questions :

```
The .id files have a 8 bytes id while the other files just need 4 bytes. 
Why is the size different?
```

.

```
In the neostore.nodestore.db, a node is represented by 14 bytes. We have :
    1 :        in-use flag
    2 to 5 :   id of the first relation
    6 to 9 :   id of the first property
    10 to 13 : id of the first label
The 14th byte is always 00 for me, what does it mean?
```

.

```
About how you make the difference between 
a short string (which can be stocked like the primitives properties) 
and a long string (which has to be stocked in a separate file).
In the article, it is said that the limit is 3 blocks and a half.
There may be no direct relation to neo4j but I've tried several strings
the same length strings don't produce the same result (one goes with other properties, the other goes to the separate file).
Can someone explain why?
```

.

```
When a long string is stocked in the neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names file, 
each record takes 128 bytes. I don't fully understand the structure :
    1 to 3 : ???
    4 : length of the string
    5 to 8 : ??? (always ff ff ff ff for me, which makes me think about a link but...)
    9 to 128 : content of the string
```

One last question :

```
In the file neostore.propertystore.db.index, the 2 to 5 bytes are always 00 to me.
In the article, it is said that it represents the property count.
Any additionnal information?
```

--

Sorry for the long post, didn't know if I had to make one or several posts...
Hope my questions are understandable.

Thanks!

Comment: be cautious as this has changed with 2.0.

Comment: Yes, I am already in 2.0 and I couldn't find an updated description of the internal yet.

Comment: Hmm, I know Tobias Lindaaker gave an updated presentation at a User Group last year, but I cannot manage to find it now :-/